# Why is my LINQ DataClass Context Object not showing up?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

Here is an image of my project's tree view:

[image]

As you can see, My linq data object resides in the App_Code folder under 'FYI'.

When I open the ControlPanel.ascx and add the LinqDataSource object, then go to select the context object this is what I see:

[image]

I am baffled as to why it is not showing up. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to always rebuild your project or solution after creating (or modifying) your Linq Context Object. The code for those data classes is actually generated at build-time, so it does not exist until you do so. This catches a **lot** of people, so don't feel bad about asking this one :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to build the project...